# Разница между this и getApplicationContext()

Tags: java, android

В чем разница между ними - разве не оба возвращают текущий контекст?

Вылетает ошибка, если использую `getApplicationContext()`. Работает, если передаю `MainActivity.this`:

```
btnClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
        dialogBuilder.setTitle("Alert dialog");
        dialogBuilder.setMessage(getApplicationContext().toString());
        AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }
});
```

Comment: А не могли бы скинуть лог ошибки

Comment: Уже пояснили,что в AlertDialog нельзя передавать context с помощью getAplicationContext()

Answer (score 1):

Вообще разница состоит в том что `getApplicationContext()` возвращает ссылку на `Application` [подробнее здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641144/difference-between-getcontext-getapplicationcontext-getbasecontext-and). Без лога ошибки не понятно в чем проблема. Да и в целом не совсем ясно что вы хотите увидеть от `getApplicationContext().toString()` или от `MainActivity.this.toString()`.

Comment: 1630-1630/com.sidorov.database E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:677)

Comment: Проблема в том что вы не можете отображать диалог при помощи контекста `Application`. [Подробнее здесь](http://tech.shantanugoel.com/2010/07/08/badtokenexception-android-dialog-getapplicationcontext.html). Для решения проблемы замените в конструкторе билдера `getApplicationContext()` на `MainActivity.this`